# How do I make a function to get the entire list of users that are registered on my dapp from the ethereum blockchain?

Tags: ethereum, solidity, go-ethereum

Please can somebody help? How do I make a function to get the entire list of users that are registered on my dapp from the ethereum blockchain?

contract SuperMail {

```
struct Mail{

    int serialNumber;
    string title;
    string content;
    string time;
    address _sender;
    address reciever;
}

struct Inbox{
    int numberOfRecievedMails;
    int numberOfSentMails;

    mapping(int => Mail) receivedMails;
    mapping(int => Mail) sentMails;
}

mapping(address => Inbox) users;
mapping(address => bool) registerd;



function checkUser(address _address) public{

    if(!registerd[_address]){
        registerd[_address] = true;

        //users[_address] = inbox;

    }


}

function getTotalReceivedMails(address _address) view public returns(int){
    return users[_address].numberOfRecievedMails;
}

function getTotalSentMails(address _address) view public returns(int){
    return users[_address].numberOfSentMails;
}

//function to send Mail
function sendMail(address recieverAddress, address senderAddress, string memory Title, string memory Content, string memory Time)  public{

    checkUser(recieverAddress);
    checkUser(senderAddress);

    users[senderAddress].numberOfSentMails++;
    users[recieverAddress].numberOfRecievedMails++;


    Mail memory mail;

    mail.title  = Title;
    mail.reciever = recieverAddress;
    mail._sender = senderAddress;
    mail.time = Time;
    mail.content = Content;
    mail.serialNumber = getTotalReceivedMails(recieverAddress);

    Inbox storage inboxR = users[recieverAddress];
    Inbox storage inboxS = users[senderAddress];
    inboxR.receivedMails[getTotalReceivedMails(recieverAddress)] = mail;
    inboxS.sentMails[getTotalSentMails(senderAddress)] = mail;



}



function getRecievedMail(address _address, int serialNumber) public view returns(string memory ,string memory, string memory, address){
    string memory content =   users[_address].receivedMails[serialNumber].content;
    string memory Title = users[_address].receivedMails[serialNumber].title;
    string memory time = users[_address].receivedMails[serialNumber].time;
    address _add = users[_address].receivedMails[serialNumber]._sender;
    return (time, Title, content, _add);
}

function getSentMail(address _address, int serialNumber) public view returns(string memory ,string memory, string memory,address){
    string memory content =   users[_address].sentMails[serialNumber].content;
    string memory Title = users[_address].sentMails[serialNumber].title;
    string memory time = users[_address].sentMails[serialNumber].time;
    address _add = users[_address].sentMails[serialNumber].reciever;
    return (time, Title, content, _add);
}
```

}

Please can somebody help? How do I make a function to get the entire list of users that are registered on my dapp from the ethereum blockchain?
I know how to get user detail by making a getter function by adding there address but its for a single user . I want a whole list of users that are registered please some body help to make the function.

Comment: ` I know how to get user detail by making a getter function by adding there address but its for a single user . I want a whole list of users that are registered please some body help to make the function.` Note that you cannot process full lists in a single transaction, as your transaction will run out of the gas. You need to design your smart contracts so that there is no need to run a long loops in Solidiity.

Answer (score 0):

You're storing the registered users in the `registerd` mapping. However, mappings are not iterable, so if you need to get the list of all registered users, you need to store them in an array.

Depending on your use case, you can either add the array next to the mapping, or replace the mapping by the array.

```
mapping(address => bool) registerd;
address[] public registeredArray; // added the array
```

```
function checkUser(address _address) public {
    if(!registerd[_address]) {
        registerd[_address] = true;
        registeredArray.push(_address); // push to the array
    }
}
```

Because of the existing logic, checking if the `registerd[_address]` value is `true`, you will not have duplicates in the `registeredArray`. So if the user executes the function twice, their address will only be stored once in the `registeredArray`.

And because the `registeredArray` is `public`, off-chain apps and other contracts can read it (cannot write) using the auto-generated getter function `registeredArray()`.